# WordPress Blog index page with repeating click event not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress-theming

I'm fairly new to jQuery and am using the following to hide and display content in a WordPress theme.

It's a blog index page, so there are a lot of repeating classes. I need a way to click on one blog post image and add a class only to it, so that only its content is displayed. Managed to do that. Then I need to be able to click on a button in the revealed content to hide it again.

I tried to have the click remove the active class, but it didn't work. I could only get the button to hide the active window, and only once. Basically it works exactly how I want it to, but only once for each blog post, then nothing.

```
//clicking on a service circle makes it active and reveals its content
$('.service-circle').on('click',function(){
  $('.service-circle').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});

//clicking on the close button hides content of active service circle
$('.close-button').on('click',function(){
    $('.service-circle.active .hidden-content').hide();
});
```

Don't know if the template setup is helpful, but here's that too:

```
    <div class="service-circle">
        <div class="hidden-content">
            <div class="close-button">X</div>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.service-circle {
width:100%;
-webkit-border-radius:50%; 
-moz-border-radius:50%; 
border-radius:50%;
float:left;
position:relative;
box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #ccc;
cursor:pointer !important;
}
.service-circle:after {
content:"";
display:block;
padding-bottom:100%;
}
.hidden-content {
display:block;
width:60%;
height:60%;
padding:0;
position:fixed;
z-index:9;
top:-100%;
left:-100%;
background:#f3f3f3;
box-shadow:1px 1px 2px 1px #999;
transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.service-circle.active .hidden-content {
top:20%;
left:20%;
transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.close-button {
width:50px;
height:50px;
background:#e86d1f;
-webkit-border-radius:50%; 
-moz-border-radius:50%; 
border-radius:50%;
position:absolute;
top:-25px;
right:-25px;
color:#fff;
font-weight:700;
line-height:50px;
font-size:25px;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Could you share some of your css. I think I need to change my answer to take propogation into account. Clicking on close button might be firing twice because of it.

Comment: added. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Cheers. Renewed code coming up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use jQuery `.each()` in your function to apply to code to each of the dynamically generated posts and then you can use either `.addClass` `.removeClass` or `.toggleClass` depending on what you need to do. You also need to add `.stopPropagation` because `.close-button` is nested within`.service-circle` so the `.active` is being remove by one function and added by another. I'm also using `.find()` to find the child element `.close-button` and similarly using `.find()` to find the grandparent `.service-circle`. Hope all that makes sense.

```
$('.service-circle').each(function(){ 
    $(this).on('click' , function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    $(this).find('.close-button').on('click' ,function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parents('.service-circle').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: So the above works if I remove all of my original jQuery. It doesn't exclusively close with the button. If I click anywhere in the content it has the desired effect. I can live with the button being a visual suggestion. Thanks again!

Comment: @MatthewWright Thanks. Glad to help. I've edited the answer to fix the above problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.service-circle').on('click',function(){
  $(this).addClass('hide');
});
```

the class "hide" will automatically hide the content